# How to compute this current value using no arbitrage condition?

Tags: stochastic-processes, no-arbitrage-theory, self-study, geometric-brownian

Suppose $X_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$. $X_0$ is known. You have a machine that produces something worth $X_t$ at random times $t$ generated by a Poisson process with fixed intensity $\lambda$. Suppose you are risk-neutral, the risk-free rate is $r$, and markets are perfectly competitive. Compute the current value of this machine (as a function of $X_0, \mu, \sigma, \lambda$ and $r$).

---

The professor gives a hint that this is a compound Poisson process. However, since the jump process is a GBM, not iid, I was still confused about how to tackle this problem.

---

I have some starting points, but I am not sure if these make sense. Denote the first arrival as $t_1$. By the property of the Poisson process, the density of $t_1$ is
$$
f_{t_1}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}, \forall t>0
$$
Let $V(x)$ denote the value of the machine conditioning on the GBM is currently at level $x$. Therefore,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} \cdot (E[X_t]+E[V(X_t)]) \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt=V(X_0)
$$
But I have no idea about how to solve this equation.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Am I correctly interpreting the machine as producing more than one unit in total, i.e. it produces one unit at random times $t_1, t_2, \ldots$ each? I do not yet see the connection to a compound process in that case. I'd guess that the discounted expected value at any random future $t$ is $E(X_t)=X_0e^{(\mu-r)t}$ (physical measure), and that the probability of receiving one unit in $t$ is $P(N_t=1)=\lambda dt$, arriving at something like $X_0\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\mu-r)t} \lambda dt=X_0\frac{\lambda}{r-\mu}$ for $r>\mu$, but that does not feel right, does it?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes, the machine could produce multiple items at random times $t_1$, $t_2$, ... The intuition makes sense, and I will follow your suggestions and give it a try. Thanks again!